# Parameters are removed when opening local URL in default browser

Tags: java

I have the following code for opening a local web page with a parameter:

```
String url = "file:///C:/work/my_page.html?";
String params = "message=HelloWorld";

Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI(url + params));
```

But, when the browser is opened, the parameters string (`?message=HelloWorld`) is removed.

While when I call some page with `http://` prefix, it does work.

How can I make it work also with local file ? (i.e. such that starts with `file:///`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a workaround that solves it. It abuses the fact that from the browser, it's possible to redirect to another page with parameters, even though the target page is local.

**Instead of calling the URL directly from Java, do the following:**

Create a temporary HTML file. Into this temporary file print an HTML code that will automatically redirect the browser to the real URL you want to open. Example:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=file:///C:/work/my_page.html?message=helloWorld" />
```

Then, just launch the browser on the temp HTML file, which will immediately redirect you to the real URL  :)

Here is the Java code for doing it in one line:

```
String url = "file:///C:/work/my_page.html?";
String params = "message=HelloWorld";

Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI(createHtmlLauncher(url + params)));
```

The method `createHtmlLauncher()`:

```
private String createHtmlLauncher(String targetUrl) throws Exception {          
    String launcherFile = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") + "local_launcher.html";
    File launcherTempFile = new File(launcherFile);         
    PrintWriter writer = null;
    try {
        writer = new PrintWriter(launcherTempFile, "UTF-8");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception("Error opening file for writing: " + launcherTempFile.getAbsolutePath() + " : " + e.getMessage());
    }
    writer.println("<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0; url=" + targetUrl + "\" />");
    writer.close();

    return "file:///" + launcherFile.replace("\\", "/");        
}
```

Note that for avoiding filling the disk with a lot of temp files, this code uses the same file for redirection each time. It means that if you open a few pages without any delay, you'll probably have race problems.

The solution is to use a generated temp file instead. The disadvantage of it is that you can't know when to remove these files from the disk. If you don't delete them and you have some extreme usage of the feature, the disk can get full.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot.
http:// is one protocol which allows parameters.
file:// is another protocol which does not allow parameters.

Suggestion is - create local web site (for example jetty) and use http potocol only. BTW, all other http stuff like AJAX will not work either.

Comment: Just a note - when I manually add the parameter in the browser's address bar, it does accept the parameter and I can print it from the JS. So maybe it is possible to do it also when launching it from a hyperlink or from some API

Comment: I guess there is a way to solve it... It worked with hyperlink -  I created another local file in the same directory and used `<a href = 'my_page.html?message=Hello'>click here</a>`, it did work.

Comment: I posted my workaround below, I guess it's less work than starting a server :)